How do I use JWT token authentication for API requests with rest_framework_simplejwt without needing user identification?
I have an API endpoint for my django application where I am allowing anyone with the JWT access token (valid for 15 mins) to use the API. But it doesn't work when I do a GET request with the access token. Authentication responds with "Token contained no recognizable user identification". Since anyone should be allowed to access the API with the token, I don't need to check if it's valid for any particular user.
JWT is a requirement in the project to have stateless user authentication for other APIs.
What is the correct/standard way to avoid this? Do I need a custom class or is there any better method to implement token authentication for APIs?

please share your rest_framework_simplejwt setup/configuration code. And  how are you sending the authorization header with the access token from the client? If you don't add 'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES' before the access token it won't work.

@MasudDipu I am sending the token as Bearer <Token> in Authorization key of header. I have figured it out with a hack. A custom authentication class that inherits BaseAuthentication from simplejwt. Validity of token is checked and only the validated token is returned with user info as None. A custom permissions class checks for authentication status and returns bool. That fixed my problem. simplejwt assumes client will send user info. Thanks!

I figured it out.
Added two classes - Custom authentication and permission classes.
AnonAuthentication Class. Just checks if the token is provided, if provided check if the token is valid.
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken, TokenError
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication

class AnonAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth_header = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        if not auth_header:
            return None

        try:
            prefix, token = auth_header.split()
            if prefix.lower() != 'bearer':
                return None
        except ValueError:
            return None

        try:
            validated_token = AccessToken(token)
            return (None, validated_token)
        except TokenError:
            raise InvalidToken('Token is invalid or expired')

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return 'Bearer realm="api"'

A custom permission class only checks if the token is authorized or not.
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class IsAuthenticatedOrToken(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.auth)

Example:
class CustomAPIListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = CustomModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrToken] 
    authentication_classes = [AnonAuthentication]
    ...

